# Magento-Clear Redis Session Cache and Code Cache

Tags: php, magento, caching, redis

I have implemented Redis Session and code cache, so it has overridden Magento's default caching mechanism. Please suggest how can this cache be cleared?

Comment: `# redis-cli flushall`

Comment: is there a way i can achieve this, without a manual command?